# Recovering data on 20TB RAID 5 NAS, overwritten by 500gb RAID 1

Tags: linux, raid, data-recovery, nas, raid-5

I have a Linux gateway with 2 500gb drives in software RAID 1 for system.

```
/dev/sda = RAID 1
/dev/sdb = RAID 1
/dev/sdc = RAID 5 (NAS 12 drives iSCSI, /home directories)
```

While replacing sdb, weird thing happened, NAS mounted as /dev/sdb at reboot, so RAID recovery procedure happily recovered RAID 1 system drive on the NAS, overwriting some data and partition table. The process was interrupded by me, when I saw what is happening.

Now I have end up with 1 broken partiton of 500gb on the 20TB NAS.

Of course I have some users that do not have backups, some 4TB data of high importance is lost somewhere on the NAS, other things can be dumped.

I believe that the data is still there, only partitions are lost.

I have tried testdisk, after 4 days of analysis, I only get this "new" broken partitions:

```
Disk /dev/sdc - 20 TB / 18 TiB - CHS 2431671 255 63
 Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
 D Linux                    0   1  1 59999 254 63  963899937 [root]
 D Linux RAID               0   1  1 59999 254 63  963899937 [md0]
```

I can even read some of the “new” data that I don't want. No sign of real data.

Any ideas what can be done?

Comment: RAID is not a backup

Comment: I can invite you to explain that to users that are bombarded every day with notes that the files on this array should be backed up manually :(

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar cases where the start of a filesystem was mistakenly overwritten. Recovery is sometimes possible by mounting the filesystem with a backup superblock.